# React-router-dom Redirect not working - shows error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

My react app react-router-dom not work. It shows error

> TypeError:
>   path_to_regexp__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8___default.a.compile is not a
>   function

**Check out image**

[image: Uncaught TypeError: path_to_regexp__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8___default.a.compile is not a function show error in react app]

---

I'm not sure why show that error problem with react-router-dom

**Check my code**

That code shows error

---

```
import React from 'react'
import DefaultLayout from './Component/Layout/DefaultLayout';
import DefaultLogin from './Component/Login/DefaultLogin';
import DefaultSignup from './Component/Sign-up/DefaultSignup';



// react-router-dom

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";


// bootstrap css
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

// css for global 
import './App.scss';


export default function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <Router>   

                <Switch> 
                        <Route path="/admin" exact component={DefaultLayout} />
                        <Route path="/admin/signup"  component={DefaultSignup} />
                        <Route path="/admin/login"  component={DefaultLogin} />
                        <Redirect from="/" to="/admin" />
                </Switch> 


            </Router>            
        </>
    )
}
```

---

### check my code

That code does not show an error but **rest app not working** because I use **Redirect**, 
out of **Switch** component

---

```
export default function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <Router>   

                <Switch> 
                        <Route path="/admin" exact component={DefaultLayout} />
                        <Route path="/admin/signup"  component={DefaultSignup} />
                        <Route path="/admin/login"  component={DefaultLogin} />

                </Switch> 

                {/* this show not error but rest app not work proper */}
                   <Redirect from="/" to="/admin" />

            </Router>            
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Refer this documentation: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect

Answer (score 7):

This error usually occurs because create-react-app installs express module which you can see in package.lock.json and it further installs path-to-regexp with an older version say 0.1.7 but in order to make react-router to work it needs version 1.7.0 or higher.
So, you can install path-to-regexp module(npm i path-to-regexp) in the application and restart the application. Everything will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the **node_modules** folder, deleted **package-lock.json** file, and run an "npm install". That fixed my issue.